# How do you nest XSL selects so you don't have to use the same XPaths

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transform

I have the below XSL which works as required. However it feels messy having to reuse the same `Customer/Personnel` XPath over and over again. Is there a way I could nest the XSL so that anything within that nested node uses the same prefix XPath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <ContactInternal>
            <xsl:attribute name="UserShortName" select="Customer/Personnel/Party/ShortName" />
            <xsl:attribute name="UserName" select="Customer/Personnel/Party/Name" />
            <xsl:attribute name="Email" select="Customer/Personnel/Party/ContactAddresses/ContactAddress/EmailAddress/EMail" />
            <xsl:if test="Customer/Personnel/Party/ContactAddresses/ContactAddress/Telephone/Number">
              <xsl:attribute name="Telephone" select="Customer/Personnel/Party/ContactAddresses/ContactAddress/Telephone/Number" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="Customer/Personnel/JobTitle">
              <xsl:attribute name="JobTitle" select="Customer/Personnel/JobTitle" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="Customer/Personnel/Branch/Code">
              <xsl:attribute name="BranchCode" select="Customer/Personnel/Branch/Code" />
            </xsl:if>
        </ContactInternal>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry if this has been asked before. I have tried to have a look around for an answer but feel I may just be searching for the wrong thing.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: There's some confusion about XSLT versions here. The stylesheet says version="1.0" but it's using `xsl:attribute/@select` which requires XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to store the nodes that you're using more than once:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="personnel"
                  select="Customer/Personnel" />
    <xsl:variable name="party"
                  select="$personnel/Party" />
    <xsl:variable name="contactAddress"
                  select="$party/ContactAddresses/ContactAddress" />
    <root>
        <ContactInternal>
            <xsl:attribute name="UserShortName" select="$party/ShortName" />
            <xsl:attribute name="UserName" select="$party/Name" />
            <xsl:attribute name="Email" select="$contactAddress/EmailAddress/EMail" />
            <xsl:if test="$contactAddress/Telephone/Number">
              <xsl:attribute name="Telephone" select="$contactAddress/Telephone/Number" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$personnel/JobTitle">
              <xsl:attribute name="JobTitle" select="$personnel/JobTitle" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$personnel/Branch/Code">
              <xsl:attribute name="BranchCode" select="Customer/Personnel/Branch/Code" />
            </xsl:if>
        </ContactInternal>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Additionally, you can make this less verbose by using [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="personnel"
                  select="Customer/Personnel" />
    <xsl:variable name="party"
                  select="$personnel/Party" />
    <xsl:variable name="contactAddress"
                  select="$party/ContactAddresses/ContactAddress" />
    <root>
        <ContactInternal UserShortName="{ $party/ShortName }"
                         UserName="{ $party/Name }"
                         Email="{ $contactAddress/EmailAddress/EMail }">
            <xsl:if test="$contactAddress/Telephone/Number">
              <xsl:attribute name="Telephone" select="$contactAddress/Telephone/Number" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$personnel/JobTitle">
              <xsl:attribute name="JobTitle" select="$personnel/JobTitle" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$personnel/Branch/Code">
              <xsl:attribute name="BranchCode" select="Customer/Personnel/Branch/Code" />
            </xsl:if>
        </ContactInternal>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to JLRishe's answer, in XSLT 3.0 you can make this more compact still:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="3.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="personnel"
                  select="Customer/Personnel" />
    <xsl:variable name="party"
                  select="$personnel/Party" />
    <xsl:variable name="contactAddress"
                  select="$party/ContactAddresses/ContactAddress" />
    <root>
        <ContactInternal UserShortName="{ $party/ShortName }"
                         UserName="{ $party/Name }"
                         Email="{ $contactAddress/EmailAddress/EMail }">
            <xsl:where-populated>
              <xsl:attribute name="Telephone"
                             select="$contactAddress/Telephone/Number" />
              <xsl:attribute name="JobTitle" 
                             select="$personnel/JobTitle" />
              <xsl:attribute name="BranchCode"
                             select="$personnel/Branch/Code" />
            </xsl:where-populated>
        </ContactInternal>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with template rules:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <ContactInternal>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ContactInternal>
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ShortName">
  <xsl:attribute name="UserShortName" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name">
  <xsl:attribute name="UserName" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EMail">
  <xsl:attribute name="Email" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

...
```

(qualifying the patterns as, for example `match="Party/Name"` if necessary for disambiguation).